# Space inside \itemize is not copied from PDF generated by overleaf

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

I was trying to generate my Resume in overleaf and only inside the \item / \itemize section the spaces are not copied, just characters without spacing until the dot.

In the Overleaf preview it works fine but when downloaded as PDF the issue persist accross all the \itemize items?

Comment: white space is (usually) not encoded in a pdf file so copying text out of a pdf always involves some heuristics by the pdf reader as to what text it places in the clipboard, it's highly dependent on the specific pdf reader you are using.

Comment: you could try `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-I}\tagpdfsetup{activate-all=false}` before `\documentclass`. With pdflatex + lualatex it should improve the space handling (if the files on overleaf are new enough).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "characters without spacing until the dot". E.g., are you reporting that all interword spacing is suppressed in the item? Does the text belonging to an item maybe contain a `$` symbol?